# How set field of subclass in composition

Tags: java, composition

I want to set text in C class using standard setter but without creating new instance like this:

```
C c = new C();

c.setText("text")

B b = new B();

b.setC(c);

A a = new A();

a.setB(b);
```

Next i want to use instance of a in some method.

Is there other simplest solution to do that without using constructor?

```
class A {  
 private B b;

// getter setter }

class B {  
 private C c; 

//getter setter }

class C {  
 private String text;

// getter seter }
```

Comment: `C.text = "Text"` works if you need a class variable. But it will probably not work if you set it as private

Comment: Fields must be private.

Comment: `C.setText("Text")` then

Comment: You can make the variable static and access it using classname to avoid making instances.
Not sure I understand what you mean by this: "Next i want to use a object in some method."

Comment: Your question is a bit blurry. Can you maybe explain it in a more sophisticated manner? We are not able to help you right now, as we don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean. My guess is that you want to expose methods of B and C using class A. If this is the case, all you have to do is wrap their methods.

```
public class A {
    private B b;
    ...

    public A() {
      b = new B();
      ...
    }

    public void setCText(String text) {
      b.setCText(text);
    }
...
}
```

All you need to do is to have B instantiate C and follow the same pattern of Class A.  That said, this is a TERRIBLE way to accomplish this.

It is OK for A to be composed of B (and other parts), and for B to be composed of C (and other parts). What is not OK is to go through all layers of composition to update a part of the whole. You need to use other design patterns to accomplish this. For example, you can subscribe class C to receive some notification when something has changed and use that as the trigger to update the text (String) field of the class.

Likewise, if class A needs to know when one of its parts has changed, you can use of other patterns. This problem sounds like it can be solved using the [Composite Design Pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/composite-design-pattern/)